# Fetching data from server (mysql databse) to android application and saving it into sqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, json, performance, android-asynctask

I am working on a project in which i have to get data tables present in mysql database on server. Now i have to insert that tables in my android application.

I had successfully achieve that functionality using `Json` Parsing and `asynctask` and `sqlitedatabase`, I have written `php` code by which i am fetching data from mysql server to my application.

Problem in this approach :

1. Time : As i am fetching that data from server in my Launcher Activity, My activity starts and take about 10 min to get all data from server. I want to reduce that time, I dont want that much delay, 5-10 sec will be fine
2. Everytime my application starts it goes in that fetching mode. which result in 10 min of loading page.
   I dont want this, I want something that checks for the changes in database present on server, if there is a change then it should start fetching on background itself. I am thiking of service with alarm manager , but i dont know how to achieve all that with service. Should i use asyncTask in service or something else.

I am not sure if that detail is sufficient or not but i will give you detail explanation if needed. Any help in this will be appreciated, If my approach is wrong then I would be more then happy to change my approach to an optimized way.

Comment: does all of the data loading need to take place to start your app ?? Or can it be done in a background task? such that the user can keep doodling with your app when the data takes shape ?

Comment: every piece of downloading data will be used in my next activity, So i guess i have to download all data first. User cant do anything if data isnt there.

Comment: What is the approximate size of the data?

Comment: approx 6-10mb can be more or less , because data is updated sometime

Comment: then if the user's data connection speed is more then 10 MBPS then there is chances of getting work done in 10 sec :(

Comment: instead you can do it with flag values. Maintain the flag in background download task and leave the UI free for user and check whether the task is done or not before the next action taken by the user.

Comment: yes i thought of that, but user will not be able to use app , because every thing should be present in sqlite database at a time to use.

Comment: Use sync Adapter, service , GCM to load data in background

Comment: i have read this , but how exactly i can do that? any help in that?

Comment: Does the server have to send all records or just the new/updated ones each time the app starts?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Java threads** instead of AsyncTask.In thread you could not access the UI.But performance point of view java thread is efficient for downloading large data.

Here some benefits of thread:

- Network operations which involve moderate to large amounts of data
  (either uploading or downloading)
- High-CPU tasks which need to be run
  in the background.

Comment: exactly how fast it can be? downloading data isnt only problem i have to store data in my sqlite database also.

Comment: total time taken in doing all getting and inserting into my sqlite database is 6-10 min,

Comment: See @bangrang based on the network speed only you can download or upload the data as your convenient...My solution is for efficient way of access the web server data in android.

Comment: i know i can do that quicker with high speed, but here its not only about speed, its about approach.

Comment: @bangrang K..Thread won't affect your UI.So it performance is fast for both download as well as stored in sqlite also.It consumes less time interval.that's way i suggest thread.